# How can I uniquely union two array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am trying to merge two arrays of objects without using the `unionBy` method from lodash.

Currently I have the following code working perfectly:

```
var array1 = [
 { a: 1, b: 'first'},
 { a: 2, b: 'second'}
];

var array2 = [
 { a: 3, b: 'third'},
 { a: 1, b: 'fourth'}
];

var array3 = __.unionBy(array2, array1, 'a');
```

This outputs:

```
[
  {
    "a": 3,
    "b": "third"
  },
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": "fourth"
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": "second"
  }
]
```

This is the desired result but I can't use `unionBy` in my current work environment, so I'm looking for a result that uses either native JS or other lodash methods 3.6.0 or lower.

Comment: how about implementing the basics of `unionBy` in your own code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a helper object to remove duplicates:

```js
var array1 = [{"a":1,"b":"first"},{"a":2,"b":"second"}];

var array2 = [{"a":3,"b":"third"},{"a":1,"b":"fourth"}];

var result = array2.concat(array1).filter(function(o) {  
  return this[o.a] ? false : this[o.a] = true;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

If ES6 is an option you can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of the helper object:

```js
const array1 = [{"a":1,"b":"first"},{"a":2,"b":"second"}];

const array2 = [{"a":3,"b":"third"},{"a":1,"b":"fourth"}];

const result = array2.concat(array1).filter(function(o) {  
  return this.has(o.a) ? false : this.add(o.a);
}, new Set());

console.log(result);
```

If you want to use an arrow function, you can't use the `thisArg` of `Array.filter()` to bind the `Set` as the `this` of the function (you can't bind `this` to arrow functions). You can use a closure instead (attribute for the method goes to @NinaScholz).

```js
const array1 = [{"a":1,"b":"first"},{"a":2,"b":"second"}];

const array2 = [{"a":3,"b":"third"},{"a":1,"b":"fourth"}];

const result = [...array2, ...array1]
  .filter((set => // store the set and return the actual callback
      o => set.has(o.a) ? false : set.add(o.a)
    )(new Set()) // use an IIFE to create a Set and store it set
  );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and easy to follow!

Comment: is there anyway to write this with  arrow function? "this" here is the array itself, right? it works but little bit of explanation would be lovely, thanks.

Comment: `this` is the object or the Set. The `Array.filter()` method accepts a `thisArg`, and binds it to the callback. It can't be an arrow function. I'll add an example using closures that uses an arrow function and a Set.

Comment: "set => o =>" this part is confusing for me, o is the representative of members of this set, but what is the rule of set here? Sorry I'm a bit noob.

Comment: oh, I got it, it's actually a function inside another function, you did that to have access to members of the objects which are the memebers of the set.set is parameter of the first function then o is the parameter of the second function.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for filtering to get unique values.

```js
var array1 = [{ a: 1, b: 'first' }, { a: 2, b: 'second' }],
    array2 = [{ a: 3, b: 'third' }, { a: 1, b: 'fourth' }],
    s = new Set,
    array3 = array2.map(o => (s.add(o.a), o)).concat(array1.filter(o => !s.has(o.a)));

console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ES6 Map for this. Construct it with the data, keyed by the `a` property value, and then take the values out of the Map again:

```js
var array1 = [{"a":1,"b":"first"},{"a":2,"b":"second"}],
    array2 = [{"a":3,"b":"third"},{"a":1,"b":"fourth"}];

var result = [...new Map([...array1,...array2].map( o => [o.a, o] )).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the 2 arrays and then filter the ones with same property `a`:

```js
var array1 = [{ a: 1, b: 'first'},{ a: 2, b: 'second'}],
  array2 = [{ a: 3, b: 'third'},{ a: 1, b: 'fourth'}],
  array3 = [...array2, ...array1].filter((item, pos, arr) =>
    arr.findIndex(item2 => item.a == item2.a) == pos);

console.log(array3)
```

If you want to still be able to specify the property by which to union you can implement you own function like this:

```js
var array1 = [{ a: 1, b: 'first'},{ a: 2, b: 'second'}],
  array2 = [{ a: 3, b: 'third'},{ a: 1, b: 'fourth'}],
  array3 = unionBy(array1, array2, 'a');

function unionBy(array1, array2, prop){
  return [...array2, ...array1].filter((item, pos, arr) =>
      arr.findIndex(item2 => item[prop] == item2[prop]) == pos);
}

console.log(array3);
```

Note: One advantage of my answer over some of the answers is that it preserves the order like in lodash which may or may not be important.

Answer (score 0):

ES5 using `Array.filter` and `Array.find`

```js
var array1 = [{ a: 1, b: "first" }, { a: 2, b: "second" }];

var array2 = [{ a: 3, b: "third" }, { a: 1, b: "fourth" }];

function merge(a, b, prop) {
  var reduced = a.filter(function(itemA) {
return !b.find(function(itemB) {
  return itemA[prop] === itemB[prop];
});
  });
  return reduced.concat(b);
}

console.log(merge(array1, array2, "a"));
```

ES6 arrow functions

```js
var array1 = [{ a: 1, b: "first" }, { a: 2, b: "second" }];

var array2 = [{ a: 3, b: "third" }, { a: 1, b: "fourth" }];

function merge(a, b, prop) {
  const reduced = a.filter(
itemA => !b.find(itemB => itemA[prop] === itemB[prop])
  );
  return reduced.concat(b);
}

console.log(merge(array1, array2, "a"));
```

Another ES6 one line experiment

```js
var array1 = [{ a: 1, b: "first" }, { a: 2, b: "second" }];

var array2 = [{ a: 3, b: "third" }, { a: 1, b: "fourth" }];

const merge = (a, b, p) => a.filter( aa => ! b.find ( bb => aa[p] === bb[p]) ).concat(b);

console.log(merge(array1, array2, "a"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ES6 find and reduce function smartly!

```js
var array1 = [{"a":1,"b":"first"},{"a":2,"b":"second"}];
var array2 = [{"a":3,"b":"third"},{"a":1,"b":"fourth"}];
var res = array1.concat(array2).reduce((aggr, el)=>{
    if(!aggr.find(inst=>inst.a==el.a))
        return [...aggr, el];
    else
        return aggr
},[])

console.log(res);
```